# Add additional data to Linq to SQL result

Tags: linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I have Linq to SQL query which return one field with Url and I bind it to asp.net combobox. I need to add new virtual record("All Url") to Linq to SQL result before binding the result. How to do that?

```
        var results =
            dataAccess.Statistics.
            Where(s => s.DateStamp >= minDate && s.DateStamp <= DateTime.UtcNow && s.UserId == userId).
            GroupBy(s => s.Url).
            Where(g => g.Count() > 1).
            OrderBy(g => g.Count()).
            Select(g => new { Url = dataAccess.getDomain(g.Key) });



        ddlDomain.DataSource = results;
        ddlDomain.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an item to the combobox, then append the databound items:

```
ddlDomain.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "All Url" });
ddlDomain.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
ddlDomain.DataSource = results;
ddlDomain.DataBind();
```